# Example of weak derivative on multivariable function

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

In order to explain about the concept of weak derivatives, I plan to give examples on them. I already manage one example for the single-variable case, but I think it would be better if I can provide one for the multi-variable case. But I'm stucked.

Can you give me an example of multi-variable function which is not classically differentiable but weakly differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

For example $\frac{1}{\|x\|}$ belongs to $W^{1,1}(B)$, $B$ is unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it is not even continuous thus not differentiable. It is discussed [here on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Examples).

Comment: So, what is the weak derivative of that function?

Comment: Just differentiate it the same way as you differentiate any function. It is $\frac{-x}{\|x\|^3}$.